# Setting Schema Structure for Proxy Service(CFX) exposed using Mule ESB

Tags: soap, wsdl, mule, mule-studio

I am very new to Mule ESB. I want to expose a Mule flow as an WebService to an external applicaton. How to set the request(payload) structure in the wsdl exposed by mule?

Am using CFX for it.

Currently my request while loading WSDL in SoapUI looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sup="http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sup:invoke>
         <sup:arg0>?</sup:arg0>
      </sup:invoke>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Actual request expected to be is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://pcom.orga.com/pc/webservices/messages/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:searchOfferRequest>
         <searchInput>
            <status>RELEASED</status>
         </searchInput>
      </v1:searchOfferRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mule [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF) for exposing a SOAP service in Mule, specifically look for the section "Creating a WSDL First JAX-WS Service" which has an example of what you are looking for.

HTH